# how to use vuetify pagination for expansion panel?

Tags: vue.js, pagination, vuetify.js

i am using Vue.js and vuex with vuetify components.
with vuex state manager i have created my state and getters for getting my data
i am using v-expansion-panel for showing data the problem is i want to have pagination for this panels i have tried the code below but its not paginating.
can anyone please help me in this case

```
<script>
    import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'

    export default {
        name: "BlueFlagProjects",
        data() {
            return {
                page: 1,
                perPage: 1,
                pages: [0,1,2,3,4,5,]
            }
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(['allblue']),
            visiblePages () {
                return this.pages.slice((this.page - 1)* this.perPage, this.page* this.perPage)
            }

        },
    }
</script>
```

```
<template>

                <v-expansion-panels
                        v-model="panel"
                        multiple
                        popout
                >
                    <v-expansion-panel v-for="items in allblue" :key="items.id">
                        <v-expansion-panel-header class="font-weight-bold">{{items.title}}
                        </v-expansion-panel-header>
                        <v-expansion-panel-content>
                            <v-row>
                                <v-col>
                                    <v-simple-table>
                                        <template v-slot:default>
                                            <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="table">Project</td>
                                                <td class="text">{{items.projectT}}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </template>
                                    </v-simple-table>
                                </v-col>
                                <v-col>
                                    <v-card class="elevation-24" width="400">
                                        <v-img src="../assets/img3.png" width="400"></v-img>
                                    </v-card>
                                </v-col>
                            </v-row>
                            <br/>
                            <p class="text font-weight-thin">
                                {{items.text}}
                            </p>
                        </v-expansion-panel-content>
                    </v-expansion-panel>
                </v-expansion-panels>

        <v-pagination
                v-model="page"
                :length="Math.ceil(pages.length/perPage)"
        ></v-pagination>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use v-data-iterator. Please check this [API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-iterator/).

Comment: For future career in SO, it would make the answer better if you are able to provide some small example for OP and/or write the relevant piece of code/snippet as an answer - many pages tend to go down when years go pass so we want to keep the answer here.